# Method of multiple values - Rasterize SAGA

Tags: qgis, polygon, saga, rasterization

I'm converting a thematic shapefile (polygons) into a raster file using the Rasterize-SAGA algorithm.

What criteria should I use to decide for  [0] last, [1] first, [2] minimum, [3] maximum, [4] mean in Method of Multiple Values?

What does the algorithm consider in each option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your target analysis. This option is for handling polygons overlapping each other.

```
[0] Last: the value of last polygon will be considered,
[1] First: the value of first polygon will be considered, 
[2] Minimum: the polygon with minimum value will be considered, 
[3] Maximum: the polygon with maximum value will be considered, and
[4] Mean: the average value of overlapping polygons will be considered.
```

After using rasterizing tool, check the output raster to confirm that this is the desired output compared to the input polygons.